# How would i read this file into a map c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, maps

I am struggling to figure out how to read this file into a map. I started by reading the file into a vector. And then was trying to take the string value in the vector and inserting that into a map. I am completely lost.

The first value is the key and the ordered pairs are the values. I need to be about to add "infinite number of values"

```
1 2,1 8,2
2 1,1 3,1
3 2,1 4,1
4 3,1 5,1
5 4,1 6,1
6 5,1 7,1
7 6,1 8,1
8 7,1 1,2
```

Current reading code:

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

     map<int, string> map;
     vector<string> v;
     vector<int>    v2;
     string line;
     string fileName(argv[1]);
     ifstream inputFile;
     inputFile.open(fileName);

     while(getline(inputFile, line)){
         v.push_back(line);
     }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::map<int,std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>>` might be what you are after, but maybe not. Please expand on how you intend to use this data. There may be better options available.

Comment: the keys are "nodes" and the values are "other node, edge length to the node" and i need to use dijkstras algorithm to find the shortest path

Comment: the keys are the first numbers 1-8 ?

Comment: Are there to be holes in the keys? As in the possibility of no node 72 through 167 but picking up again at 168?

Comment: Yes they are the keys

Comment: No there aren't any holes. The numbers are all consecutive

Comment: Pass on the `map` then if you can. `vector` of `vector` will be more efficient. `std::vector<std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>>`. The key becomes the index of outer `vector` giving you much more direct look-up.

Comment: That makes sense but how would i read that from a file and insert it in. Sorry i didn't really specify that but I'm more so struggling with reading the file.

Comment: `add "infinite number of values"` the moment you say that, you are a mathematician not a computer scientist :D :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified that the on each line the initial value is a consecutive key, and the remaining values on each line consist of whitespace-delimited tupled, which each tuple being two values separated by a comma, with the first value being some other identifier, and as such the first value of all tuples on the same line will be unique.

As such, I would suggest the following data structure:

```
typedef std::vector<std::map<int, int>> map_t;
```

the vector index would be the initial key. Your vector indexes are 0-based, and in your data file they are 1-based, but this is simple enough to handle on the fly. Either change your data file, or just proceed with the key 0 having no data.

Each value in the vector is a map. The map's key is the "other node" id, and the value is the distance to the other node -- according to your description of what this data means.

This data structure will model this data nicely. Now, as far as the matter of reading and parsing this data:

Your initial approach is correct: use `std::getline()` to read each line at a time into a string:

```
map_t my_map;

std::string line;

while (std::getline(inputFile, line)) {

    // Here be dragons

}
```

There's nothing to be gained from placing each `line` into a vector of strings, first. We can simply parse each line as we read it. Inside the loop, we'll handle each line read, and place its data directly into `my_map`. That's the plan. Simple, easy, and straightforward.

Inside the loop, we begin by placing each line into a `std::istringstream`, in order to parse it, and then extract the initial node id:

```
int node_id;

std::istringstream line_stream(line);

line_stream >> node_id;
```

Simple enough. If you need to handle bad input, you should be able to figure out how to check for conversion failures yourself here, and in the remaining code.

Now, we then simply need to pluck out each "other_node,distance" tuple pair:

```
std::string node_distance;
std::map<int, int> node_distance_map;

while (line_stream >> node_distance)
{
     // Here be more dragons.
}
```

And that's that. Inside the loop, where there are more dragons, `node_distance` will be each individual "n,n" string, with two values. That's simple enough for you to figure out, on your own: how to extract these two ints out of this string yourself; then update `node_distance_map`. Then, after this `while_loop` you take the constructed `node_distance_map`, and the `node_id` extract earlier, and stuff the whole thing into the `my_map`. Mission accomplished. That didn't seem to be very difficult, did it?

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to combine node_distance_map and node_id into the my_map. I think I have everything else.

Comment: `map_t` is a vector, and `node_id` would be its index. So, first check that the `node_id` index actually exists in the vector, and if not, `resize()` the vector so that it does. Then, it's simply `my_map[node_id]=node_distance_map;`. Nothing different from assigning any other value into any other kind of a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution, it is the not best solution but it achieves the goal:

```
map<int, vector<pair<int, int>>> result;

ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\Mohamed\\Desktop\\test.txt");

string line;
while (getline(infile, line)) {

    istringstream iss(line);
    vector<string> tokens{istream_iterator<string>{iss},
                          istream_iterator<string>{}};

    if(tokens.size() == 0) continue; // Workaround

    int pair1FirstValue, pair1SecondValue, pair2FirstValue, pair2SecondValue;

    string pair1 = tokens.at(1);
    string pair2 = tokens.at(2);

    sscanf(pair1.c_str(), "%d,%d", &pair1FirstValue, &pair1SecondValue);
    sscanf(pair2.c_str(), "%d,%d", &pair2FirstValue, &pair2SecondValue);

    vector<pair<int,int>> valueVector { make_pair(pair1FirstValue, pair1SecondValue), make_pair(pair2FirstValue, pair2SecondValue) };

    result.insert(make_pair(stoi(tokens.at(0)), valueVector));
}

cout << "Printing the map: " << endl;

for(auto it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); it++) {

    cout << it->first << " "
         << it->second.at(0).first << " " << it->second.at(0).second << " "
         << it->second.at(1).first << " " << it->second.at(1).second << endl;
}
```

In order to build the code, you'll need to include the following header files:

`#include <iostream>`
`#include <sstream>`
`#include <fstream>`

Try to understand the code, and fix the workaround, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple reading example. It is in no way optimal, but it should be easy to read, understand, debug, and get OP started. If the file reading is a heavy contributor to processing time, consider using something like a state machine.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{

    std::vector<std::map<int, int>>adjacencies;
    std::string line;

    if (argc >=2 ) // no argv[1] if argc < 2
    {
        std::ifstream inputFile(argv[1]);

        while(getline(inputFile, line)) // get a line until no more lines
        {
            std::map<int,int> temp; // holder for adjacent nodes as we find them
            std::stringstream ss(line); // stream to ease parsing of nodes from line
            std::string node;
            while (ss >> node) // get adjacent node on this line until end of line
            {
                std::stringstream ss2(node); //stream to ease taking nodes apart
                int key;
                char comma;
                int weight;
                if (ss2 >> key >> comma >> weight) // take apart node
                {
                    temp[key] = weight; // put adjacent node in list
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cerr << "File is bogus. Bailing\n";
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            adjacencies.push_back(temp); // put node and all adjacencies in list
        }

        try
        {
            auto weight_of_15_8 = adjacencies[15-1].at(8);
            //-1 because origin 0 indexing
        }
        catch(std::out_of_range &)
        {
            std::cerr << "node 15 is not adjacent to 8\n";
        }

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cerr << "Usage <prog name here> <filename here>\n";
        return -2;
    }
}
```

The exception is particularly stupidly slow, but with if a key isn't in a `map`, the `map` will create and default init the value if you use `[]`. You don't want a list full of adjacency zero nodes, so best nip that bug early.